# Notepad++ AutoCopy

Tags: notepad++

When I search for something in Notepad++ with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> I want to AutoCopy the found line. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "autocopy"? Copy the line where a match is found? Or copy to the clipboard? Please be more specific.

Comment: yes i will autocopy only the line with the match to clipboard

Comment: In SynWrite editor, there's option "Copy entire line if no selection made". so put caret on any line, and press Ctrl+C, line copied.